# Simple RAD tool for C#, MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, rad

Hy!

I have to use a RAD tool for one of my faculty project(the task is to use a RAD tool and 3 web services). Could you give me some suggestions of nice tools for C# or MVC3? I have found some services that provide information about an artist(albums, tracks, lyrics) and I would like to show this to user using a MVC3 project, maybe save the results to a database... Any RAD tool that could help me to do that?

Thanks in advance and excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

[Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/) or [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) for getting started with C# and ASP.Net MVC

Comment: WebMatrix is not really for getting started with ASP.NET MVC 3. It's for getting started with Razor, for ASP.NET MVC 3 Visual Studio is the way to go.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - The Razor `ViewEngine` is kind of a subset of MVC3. In terms of the full .Net toolkit VS is the only way to go, but for just learning the very basics WebMatrix is a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Lightswitch: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/lightswitch

if you are open for silverlight...